# What did I do wrong?

Tags: java

```
 public void giveTitle;int titleId;
          {
        this.playerTitle = titleId;
        this.setAppearanceUpdateRequired(true);
    }
```

As I compiled it, my compiler said that both "public" and "void" were illegal starts of an expression. All help would be appreciated! If I need to clarify more please ask!

Comment: It should be `giveTitle()` with `()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Trying to declare a method? or some variables followed by a block of code?

Answer (score 3):

Breaking it down:

This

```
public void giveTitle;int titleId;
{
    this.playerTitle = titleId;
    this.setAppearanceUpdateRequired(true);
}
```

Is just like saying this

```
public void giveTitle;  // declare giveTitle
int titleId;            // declare titleId

{  // brackets have no effect in this case.
    this.playerTitle = titleId;     // does not work because titleId has not 
                                    // been initialized
    this.setAppearanceUpdateRequired(true);    // 
}
```

As you can see, all you're doing above is declaring two variable, which is not what you wanted to do. You wanted to create a method.  But with what you did `public void giveTitle`, You're getting the error because you can't declare a variable with `public void`

What you wanted was this

```
public void giveTitle(int titleId)
{                                    // here the brackets encasulate what's inside
    this.playerTitle = titleId;      // making them "belong" to the method.
    this.setAppearanceUpdateRequired(true);
}
```

Just by adding this parenthesis, you turned this into a mthod that reads like this

```
public void giveTitle(int titleId)

// a method named giveTitle with a parameter of an int titleId, will set this.title
// to the titleId passed into this method, also set the appearanceUpdateRequired to true
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of a method have to be put in parentheses:

```
public void giveTitle(int titleId) { .... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
public void giveTitle(int titleId)
          {
        this.playerTitle = titleId;
        this.setAppearanceUpdateRequired(true);
    }
```